# +Dynamic creation of tab pages

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

Depending on a number a user enters in a textbox I want to create tabpages containing a gridview and textboxes.

By now I remove and re-add all tabpages when the user changes the number to be shown.

How can I change code so that I only have to add / remove the difference in tabpages?

```
private DataGridView[] rtb = new DataGridView[100];
        private TabPage[] tab = new TabPage[100];
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comp;


        public void ctp(Int32 textbox)
        {
            try
            {
                if (textbox > 10)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You Exceed Limit");
                }
                else
                {
                    int k = 0;
                    int s = 0;
                    k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    {
                        tab[i] = new TabPage();
                        //Start Gridview
                        rtb[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
                        rtb[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 50);
                        rtb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1020, 150);
                        //ID Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("tr_id", "ID");
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].Width = 1;
                        // Color Column
                         comp = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                            comp.HeaderText = "Color No";
                            //comp[i].DataPropertyName = "Color No";
                            comp.Width = 200;
                            comp.Name = "color_no";
                            comp.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
                            //comp[i].ReadOnly = false;
                            rtb[i].Columns.Add(comp);
                        //Quantity Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("quantity", "Quantity");
                        //Piece Weight Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("piece_weight", "Piece Weight");
                        //Total Weight Carton
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("total_weight", "Total Weight");
                        //Piece in Carton Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("pcs_carton", "Pcs/Carton");
                        //No Of Carton Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("no_of_carton", "Total Cartons");
                        //Unit Name Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("unit_name", "Unit Name");
                        //Rate Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("rate", "Rate");
                        //Amount Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("amount", "Amount");
                        //Ship Qty Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("ship_qty", "Ship Qty.");
                        //kdnr column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("kdnr", "KDNR");
                        //reference No Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("ref_no", "Reference No.");

                        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                        checkColumn.Name = "deleterow";
                        checkColumn.HeaderText = "Delete Row";
                        checkColumn.Width = 50;
                        checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
                        checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add(checkColumn);

                        tab[i].Controls.Add(rtb[i]);
                        tab[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
                        tab[i].Name = "tab" + i.ToString();
                        tab[i].Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
                        tab[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 242);
                        tab[i].Text = "Article" + i.ToString();
                        tab[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                        tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tab[i]);

                        //MessageBox.Show(""+tab[i].Text);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
        #region Calling Create TabPage Function
            try
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    Int32 textbox = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                    ctp(textbox);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        #endregion
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Your question is very hard to understand. Am i right when i suppose you want to enter the number of tabpages to be shown in a textbox?

Comment: yes because this input goes in db

Comment: but he wants 3 and he put 2 but next time he want 1 more so never delete previous data one more be add but input like this first time 2 second he wants one so put 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call:

```
tabControl2.TabPages.Clear();
```

That is removing all your tab pages. You need to add the *extra* pages. Work out how many you need to add on then loop through adding them like this:

```
var NewPage = new TabPage();

// Create your page here ...

// Add the page to the tabs
tabControl2.TapPages.Add(NewPage);
```

Comment: i Edit my question i do same

Comment: Er? If this answers it then no need edit your question! - that'll just make it confusing to read over.

Comment: my custom events not working because Events read textbox value

Comment: first time i enter 2 so event work 2 time fine but i want 1 more i put 1 so event work 1 time not working on previous 2

Comment: I think it's because you're clearing the tab pages: this will stop your first 2 working because you've cleared (deleted) them. Hence my answer tells you *not* to use `.Clear()` but to code it differently (so you're just adding the *new* pages)

Comment: no i can't clear tabpage but clear textbox and loop read a textbox how many you have tabpage and gridview

Comment: int k = 0;
                    k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    {
}

Comment: if textbox have 1 so event work 1 time if textbox have 2 so event work 2 time example user put in textbox 2 and 2 tabpage created but he want one more so he put 1 one more added but events read textbox value which was user put in textbox

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand - you're gonna have to do it the old fashioned way and ask a friend or teacher who speaks your lanugage. Good luck. Sorry we couldn't help.